# Applescript (.scpt) being if Tor Browser is running?

Tags: applescript

**Running: OSX 10.11.3**

So I have the script below. It is a naive hack to build an html link string based on the selected text and current url of a Firefox window. It's fragile but works ok.

However if I have [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) running in addition to Firefox and open the script in `Script Editor`, I see that the code has been changed to reference `Tor Browser`:

```
tell application "TorBrowser" to activate
```

Yikes! I know `Tor Browser` is based on Firefox – but it seems to have its own process ID (confirmed in `Activity Monitor`). Even if it didn't **why and how is the code being changed?** I've tested this numerous times:

- Without Tor Browser running: code doesn't change
- Based on its "modified date" it is not being changed after I close it in Script Editor. (i.e. save it at 11:10, leave the window open until 11:12)
- Duplicate script. Launch one copy with Tor Browser running: script is changed. Quit Tor Browser and launch second copy: script is not changed.  There is no prompt to save the changed file when closing it.

Does anyone know what is going on? This seems very bizarre. Is there a workaround?

---

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
delay 0.3

tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Firefox"
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 0.1
    end tell
    set theHeadline to the clipboard

    delay 1
    tell process "Firefox"
        keystroke "l" using command down
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 0.1

        set theUrl to the clipboard
    end tell

    set tagStart to "<a href ="
    set tagMiddle to "><b><u>"
    set tagEnd to "</u></b></a>"

    set tag to tagStart & "\"" & theUrl & "\"" & tagMiddle & theHeadline & tagEnd

    set the clipboard to tag

end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `info.plist` files, the CFBundleExecutable of these applications is "**firefox**", and the CFBundleSignature is "**MOZB**", maybe this causes this issue.

To avoid this, use the bundle identifier of the application in your script:

```
tell application id "org.mozilla.firefox" to activate
-- the bundle identifier of the "Tor Browser" application  is  "org.mozilla.tor browser"
```

---

Since the name of the processes is the same, use this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell (first process whose its bundle identifier is "org.mozilla.firefox")
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 0.1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend a couple of simple changes to your script.  When you're working with system events, there is no need to use tell process within the system events block.

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
 delay 0.3

 tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay .1
    set theHeadline to the clipboard
    keystroke "l" using command down
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.1
    set theUrl to the clipboard
end tell

set tagStart to "<a href ="
set tagMiddle to "><b><u>"
set tagEnd to "</u></b></a>"

set tag to tagStart & "\"" & theUrl & "\"" & tagMiddle & theHeadline & tagEnd

set the clipboard to tag

end tell
```

Back to your original question, your compiler (Script Editor) is trying to correct your mistake. It assumes that your are meaning Tor since it sees that running. You and I know you really mean FireFox, but it assumes you've made a mistake. The good news is once you compile it and save it as an app, this shouldn't be an issue. Just make sure when you compile and save that you don't have Tor running and I believe you should be fine.

Btw... You'll see similar behavior if you were to change FireFox to to FoxFire or something else. It will usually prompt you to select the application, then you'd have to navigate to FireFox.

- *please forgive formatting, writing this on my phone*